# Loading HTML into Webview from a string, OS X

Tags: swift, cocoa

I would like to create some formatted text using HTML in my OS X program.  I am programing in swift.  I created a web view and set up a simple test.

```
import Cocoa
import RealmSwift
import WebKit

class invociegenerator: NSViewController {
@IBOutlet var InvoiceView: WebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var htmlString:String! = "<br /><h2>Hello World!!</h2>"
    InvoiceView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
        // Do view setup here.
}

}
```

I receive an error saying "WebView does not have a member named 'LoadHTMLString'"  I must be missing something, is it possible to load from a string in an OS X program?   There are plenty of tutorials online but the all focus on iOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"loadHTMLString" is a method on a [WebFrame](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebFrame_Class/index.html) object not WebView. However, Webview does have a method that returns the mainFrame for the webview. So you could just call mainFrame on the webview like this.

```
InvoiceView.mainFrame.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```